# Git merge from master to stage overwrite conflicts

Tags: git, github, git-commit

So I have a git branch that I wrote directly to master the fixes for the files.  I was working on the files in stage in the same area.  Now I have CONFLICTS.  The problem is I'm having conflicts with about 1900 files.  I don't want to go in and fix each conflict.  Is there anyway to merge the master with stage overwriting all conflicts and taking what's in master?

Comment: I really can't understand this question

Comment: Sorry.  Basically I have a merge conflict of 1900 files. I'm trying to merge my master branch to my strange branch.  I want to know if there is anyway to force it without fixing conflicts

Comment: Not without losing your changes on your strange branch

Comment: That's not a problem. The master is up to date.  The stage is not.

Comment: Are we talking about a branch named stage or the actual git stage before files are commited ?

Comment: ah a branch named stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After understanding that stage is a branch but the changes are no longer important nor relevant. Simply using `git reset --hard master` on `stage` branch to move the branch pointer to `master` should suffice. It will put the branch `stage` on the exact same state `master` is. **THIS WILL DELETE YOUR CHANGES IN STAGE**. Use it with caution.